# How to use sass to set different media query breakpoints depending on body class

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design, scss-mixins

I'm building a set of web pages that will be served from several different sites, each templating in some site-specific content.

They're essentially identical, but just different enough that I need the media query breakpoints to be a couple (hundred) pixels different per site.

I'd like for a site to be able to template in the site name as a class on the body container, and have the correct breakpoints be used for that class/site.

I've tried multiple different approaches using mixins etc and can't get anything to work.

I currently have my breakpoints mixin defined in abstracts/_mixins.scss:

```scss
@mixin breakpoint ($breakpoint) {

    @if $breakpoint ==small {
        @media screen and (min-height: $xsmall) and (min-width: $xsmall-width) {
            @content
        }
    }

    @if $breakpoint ==medium {
        @media screen and (min-height: $small) and (min-width: $small-width) {
            @content
        }
    }
...
```

I then use these breakpoints with `@include breakpoints(small){}`

If there's a better way to do this than by setting the parent container class I'm open to that as well... I'd just prefer to not have separate stylesheets per site for maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure but wouldn't you just want to bring the information like this

```scss
@use 'info' as i; 
// the i you can use it form the information in that partial file
// partial file should have an underscore(_info.scss)
@mixin breakpoint (i.$breakpoint) {

    @if i.$breakpoint == i.$small {
        @media screen and (min-height: i.$xsmall) and (min-width: i.$xsmall-width) {
            @content
        }
    }

    @if $breakpoint == i.$medium {
        @media screen and (min-height: i.$small) and (min-width: i.$small-width) {
            @content
        }
    }
```

not 100% but maybe something like that can work